# Define start and end within ts function in data.table groupby

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I'm trying to transform a particular column of a dataset with daily samples of data for different devices into a time series column grouped by two keys (hour and factor1)

The data I have is something like this

```
         date    hour factor1 volume    wkday 
1: 2015-10-01     AM   11011    530  Thursday    
2: 2015-10-01     AM   11012   1535  Thursday    
3: 2015-10-01     AM   11021    191  Thursday    
4: 2015-10-01     AM   11131   1108  Thursday    
5: 2015-10-01     AM   11132   1518  Thursday    
6: 2015-10-01     AM   11141    508  Thursday
```

date runs from 2015-10-01 to 2017-08-01, hour has two levels (AM and PM), factor1 has many levels and wkday is not needed so far. The column I want to turn into timeseries data is volume.

I tried do this:

```
table_11011 = table[factor1 == '11011']
table_11011_am = table_11011[hour == 'AM']

table_11011_am[, vol_ts := ts(table_11011_am[,volume],
                  start = decimal_date(table_11011_am[, date][1]),
                  frequency = 365)]
```

Thus I get the desired output but when I try to summarize this for all the different factor1 levels and hours I don't know how to input the correct start and end date. So far I managed to do this but it seems to give a bad output.

```
table[, vol_ts := ts(volume,
                   start = decimal_date(table[, date][1]), frequency = 365), by = c('factor1', 'hour')]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I 100% follow the intended usage here, but here's a stab at how I might approach a similar problem.

Basically, you can use `seq.Date()` to generate a regular series of dates, then use data.table's `CJ()` (cross join) function to repeat that series for each combination of your hours and factors.

Once you have a regular series, you can join in your raw data to get the regularly spaced data I think you're looking for. I've never really dealt with specialized time-series type objects in R, I've always been able to accomplish everything I need to with the `data.table`, `zoo`, and `RcppRoll` packages.

Hope this may be of some help.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2015-10-01","2015-10-25","2015-11-04","2015-11-06")),
                 hour = c("AM","PM","AM","PM"),
                 factor1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
                 volume = c(1,2,3,4))

## Create a regular sequence of all dates in range 
## with a row for each combo of hour and factor1
TS <- CJ(Date = seq.Date(from = DT[,min(Date)], to = DT[,max(Date)],by = "day"),
         hour = DT[,unique(hour)],
         factor1 = DT[,unique(factor1)])

## Join the data to this expanded time series

setkey(DT,Date,hour,factor1)
setkey(TS,Date,hour,factor1)

TS <- DT[TS]

## Fill with zeros if necessary
TS[is.na(volume), volume := 0]

## If you want a separate column for factor level
Wide <- dcast(TS, ... ~ factor1, value.var = "volume")

## Or if you want a column (time series) for each combo
VeryWide <- dcast(TS, ... ~ factor1 + hour, value.var = "volume")
```

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I was looking for but it was very helpful. What I'm looking for is to within the same dataframe, define in some way the ts on a new column, but each ts is different, because each factor1 and hour can have different length... I don't know if I'm explaining myself. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.